# Billing Client subscription with different currencies

Tags: android, subscription

I implemented google payments for subscription with introductory period but there is an UI issue that I don't have any clue how to resolve.

So, the SkuDetails json looks like:

`{"type": "subs", "price": "$ 28.88", "price_amount_micros": 28884077, "price_currency_code": "$", "subscriptionPeriod": "P1M", "introductoryPriceAmountMicros": 790000, "introductoryPricePeriod": "P1M", "introductoryPrice": "£0.79", "introductoryPriceCycles": 1.}`

As you can see, the `introductoryPrice` has different currency than `price_currency_code`. Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: This is quite odd. I've checked and seems to be a reported similar bug. You may want to add your details to it so Google knows is happening to more developers, or open a new issue ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172834437

Comment: @PerracoLabs Thank you for this lead. I will track the issue and hope it will be solved soon.